# Swap CSS class on the basis of Scroll Position with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to re-create the Apple Store shopping cart sidebar.

http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MB535LL/A?mco=MTA4MTg3NTQ

It is similar to "position: fixed" except that it starts out as "position: absolute" with the CSS class "pinned_top" and then switches to CSS class "floating" when a certain scroll-y position is reached.

I've looked EVERYWHERE for this, it seems a tutorial should be obvious but I'm yet to find anything.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to handle the [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll) event, and check the element position, if the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.scrollTop) is greater than the position of your element, you set the element fixed at top, if not, you place the element where it originally was.

An [example](http://jsbin.com/isipa) using jQuery:

```
$(function () { 
  var $el = $('.fixedElement'), 
      originalTop = $el.offset().top;  // store original top position

  $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > originalTop ){ 
      $el.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
    } else { 
      $el.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': originalTop}); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

http://dreamstarstudios.net/sandbox/sticky_nav.html

Answer (score 0):

This working in FF3.5!

```
<div id="banner" style="border:1px solid blue;width:100%;height:100px;">
 This is a banner1
</div>
<div style="clear:left;border:1px solid green;width:70%;height:900px;top:110;">
    this is main div
</div>
<div id="fixedDiv" 
             style="clear:left;position:absolute;top:110;right:20;width:25%;
             border:1px solid red;height:500px;">
    lorem ipsum dorem dorel ipsa zeta zelga rumba lorem ipsum dorem dorel ipsa 
    zeta zelga rumba lorem ipsum dorem dorel ipsa zeta zelga rumba
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var abs=false; //dont set it again and again
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $().scroll(function(e){
  var st=$(window).scrollTop();
  //110 is top of fixedDiv
  if(st>110)
  {
                //set number to how much you want it from top!
                $("#fixedDiv").css({"top":10}); 
                if(abs) return;
                $("#fixedDiv").css({"position":"fixed"});
                abs=true;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!abs) return;
                //if we are again showing banner, change position to absolute
                $("#fixedDiv").css({"position":"absolute","top":110}); 
                abs=false;
            }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the answer above worked like a charm so please pardon me for not testing this one out.