# Apple store like sidebar with css swapping jquery technique

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to use jquery to create a div, that will stay fixed while scrolling, just like in apple store :

http://store.apple.com

Add any product to cart and you will see it appear on the right side in a div, which will stay in place if you scroll page further down.

I found this solution here:

[Swap CSS class on the basis of Scroll Position with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548765/swap-css-class-on-the-basis-of-scroll-position-with-javascript)

However there are 2 issues with that solution.:

1) It doesn't work with more recent jquery version (1.5.1 in my case)

2) I would also want the effect to work only within a certain div or td, so when you reach the end of that parent div or td while scrolling down, it will stop there. In other words, I don't want this fixed div to cover my footer content in cases where user scrolls all way down to the end of the page...

I am open for any solutions, advises, tutorials and pointers from pros like you!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Tules He specified that you need to add an item to the cart to see the effect.

Comment: the latest jQuery version is 1.6.4

Comment: what I meant by latest is later version, i knew someone would point out that 1.5.1 is not the latest, let me edit my post i guess

Comment: Can you provide more details on what isn't working for you?  Are you getting an error?  Sample code would help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the code not working with newer versions of jQuery.  It looks like nothing has changed.

For positioning so the child stays in a cell you could use this kind of approach:

```
function fixInParent(selector) {
    var $el = $(selector);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($el.parent().offset().top > $(this).scrollTop())
            $el.addClass('top').removeClass('floating').removeClass('bottom');
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() + $el.height() < $el.parent().offset().top + $el.parent().height())
            $el.addClass('floating').removeClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
        else
            $el.addClass('bottom').removeClass('top').removeClass('floating');
    });
}
```

This (while not optimized) does two checks.  First, if the page isn't yet scrolled to the top of the parent element, it sets the class to 'top'.  This would have something like `position: absolute; top: 0`.

If that fails, it checks to see of the element with fixed position would have its bottom (top of the screen + height) below the bottom of its parent (top of the parent + parent height).  If it doesn't, we set the class to 'floating', which has `position: fixed; top: 0`.

Otherwise, we don't want the element to extend past its parent so we set the class to 'bottom'.  This would have something like `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

**Update** Sample code is here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uyBRA/2/  The floating div is in the second block.

Comment: Looks pretty good, just have a question, in case if my parent is a TD with unknown height, how do I make it "relative"?

Comment: I applied your code to this example page http://cheap-kettlebells.com/so.html , but floating div disappears as soon as it reach the bottom of the parent TD and I think it due to the fact I couldn't assign "position:relative" to parent, TD in my particular case. Is there a work around?

Comment: Why can't you appliy `position:relative`?  I did it in Chrome Dev Tools on your page and it worked fine.